# trying to inject a library in my own program

Tags: c#, dll, code-injection, dll-injection, entry-point

I'm currently trying to inject a library into a program I made(for learning purpose, it's just curiosity). I think I managed to do it, but it seems the code i did is laking of entry point maybe ?

this is the code I wrote :
I used visual studio code to generate a kind of hello-world dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace InjectDll
{
    public class Inject
    {

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();

        public Inject()
        {
            AllocConsole();
            Console.WriteLine("blablabla");
        }

        public string test()
        {
            AllocConsole();
            return "dll is injected";
        }
    }
}
```

I then made a basic program I where wanted to test my injection =>

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace basicProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while(true){
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now I have my dll and the program i wanted to try my injection.I just had to write the injector, and this is what I did =>

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace injectorTest.Inject
{
    public enum DllInjectionResult
    {
        DllNotFound,
        GameProcessNotFound,
        InjectionFailed,
        Success
    }

    class Injector
    {

        static readonly IntPtr INTPTR_ZERO = (IntPtr)0;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, int bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] buffer, uint size, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttribute, IntPtr dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);

        //[DllImport("InjectDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]


        private const string DLL_NAME = "hello.dll";
        private Process myProcess;
        private string myPath;
        public Injector()
        {

        }
        public  Injector(Process myProcess)
        {
            this.myProcess = myProcess;
            this.myPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(myProcess.MainModule.FileName);
        }

        private void checkDll()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(myPath + @"\hello.dll")) {

            }
        }

        public DllInjectionResult inject()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(myPath + "\\hello.dll"))
            {
                return DllInjectionResult.DllNotFound;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("process id : " + myProcess.Id);
            if (myProcess == null)
            {
                return DllInjectionResult.GameProcessNotFound;
            }

            if (!startInject((uint)myProcess.Id, myPath + "\\hello.dll"))
            {
               return DllInjectionResult.InjectionFailed;
            }
           return DllInjectionResult.Success;
        }

        private bool startInject(uint processId, string dllPath)
        {
            IntPtr handleProcess = OpenProcess((0x2 | 0x8 | 0x10 | 0x20 | 0x400), 1, processId);

              if (handleProcess == INTPTR_ZERO)
              {
                  return false;
              }

              IntPtr lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(handleProcess, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)dllPath.Length, (0x1000 | 0x2000), 0X40);
              Console.WriteLine("lpaddr: " + lpAddress);

              if (lpAddress == INTPTR_ZERO)
              {
                  return false;
              }

              byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dllPath);

              if (WriteProcessMemory(handleProcess, lpAddress, bytes, (uint)bytes.Length, 0) == 0)
              {
                  return false;
              }

              IntPtr lpLLAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");


              if (lpLLAddress == INTPTR_ZERO)
              {
                  return false;
              }
              var remoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(handleProcess, (IntPtr)null, INTPTR_ZERO, lpLLAddress, lpAddress, 0, (IntPtr)null);
              if (remoteThread == INTPTR_ZERO)
              {
                  return false;
              }

              CloseHandle(handleProcess);

              return true;
        }


    }
}
```

It doesn't seems to fail i can see via ida (watching the helloworld program i tried to inject) that LoadLibraryW is trigered when I launch my injector (I then can see the path of the dll injected but it doesn't seems to trigger smthg.

It seems like I missing something (like an entry point in my dll maybe ?).

Comment: I never did that, but according to the documentation of LoadLibraryW: `LoadLibrary can be used to load a library module into the address space of the process and return a handle that can be used in GetProcAddress to get the address of a DLL function`. So I guess you then need to call `GetProcAddress` to get the address of the method you want to run, and invoke it (of course you should do that from a remote thread)

Comment: An alternative would be to have a `DllMain` in your injected DLL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain But this is a native method. So maybe write a C++/CLI wrapper with a DllMain and inject it. When the method get invoked, load the C# assembly through reflection and run it.

Comment: I slooks like an intestersting question, but I am not sure, that I understand right. You wrote a DLL in C# (.NET assembly). You wrote a program where you want to inject the dll into (.NET exe). Who should inject the dll into the program? The program itself during runtime? It could load the dll dynamically. An external program? What should happen inside our program (basicProgram) when the dll is injected?

Answer (score 1):

A normal C/C++ DLL will have a DllMain which gets executed when LoadLibrary is called which then passes through to a switch statement, normally we put our code inside the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH case which will get executed on injection.

This equivalent doesn't exist in C#/CLR but you can do something tricky to make the same effect by using static constructors.

Make a class and initialize an object of that class, this will in turn call the static constructor.  Something like this:

```c#
class someClass
{
   //Static constructor
   static someClass()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("injected");
   }
 }
```